# Prove the following estimate for the spherical average

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given the spherical average of f over S(x,r)
$$S_f(x,r) = \frac{1}{\sigma_{n-1}r^{n-1}} \int_{S(x,r)} f(y) d\sigma(y) $$

and the volume average

$$V_f(x,r) = \frac{1}{\omega_n r^n} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y) dy$$

How can I prove that
$$ V_{f^2}(x,r) \leq S_{f^2}(x,r)  $$
$$ \frac{1}{\omega_n r^n} \int_{B(x,r)} f^2(y) dy \leq \frac{1}{\sigma_{n-1}r^{n-1}} \int_{S(x,r)} f^2(y) d\sigma(y) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $$ \phi(r) = \frac 1 {n \omega_n r^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B_r(x)} (u(y))^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_y. $$ Observe that $\phi$ is monotone increasing. The proof of this is very similar to the proof of the Mean Value Formula for Laplace's equation, see Theorem 2 in Chapter 2.2 of *Partial Differential Equations* by Lawrence C. Evans. Indeed, by letting $y = x+rz$\begin{align*} 
\phi (r) &= \frac 1 {n \omega_n } \int_{\partial B_1(0)} (u(x+rz))^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_z,
\end{align*} so \begin{align*} 
\phi '(r) &= \frac 2 {n \omega_n } \int_{\partial B_1(0)} u(x+rz) Du(x+rz) \cdot z d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_z \\
&= \frac 2 {n \omega_n} \int_{\partial B_r(x)}  u(y) Du(y) \cdot \bigg ( \frac{y-x}{r}\bigg ) d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_y \\
&=  \frac 2 {n \omega_n} \int_{\partial B_r(x)}  u(y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu }(y) d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_y \\
&= \frac 2 {n \omega_n} \bigg ( \int_{B_r(x)} u \Delta u d y + \int_{B_r(x)} \vert Du \vert^2 d y \bigg ) \geqslant 0 .  
\end{align*} Since $\phi$ is increasing for all $0<s\leqslant r$, \begin{align*}
 \int_{\partial B_s(x)} (u(y))^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_y \leqslant \frac{s^{n-1}}{r^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B_r(x)} (u(y))^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_y.
\end{align*}

To prove your inequality use polar coordinates to find \begin{align*} 
\frac 1 {\omega_n r^n} \int_{B_r(x)} (u(y))^2 d y &= \frac 1 {\omega_n r^n} \int_0^r \int_{\partial B_s (x)} (u(y))^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1} d s \\
&\leqslant \frac 1 {\omega_n r^{2n-1}} \int_0^r s^{n-1} \int_{\partial B_r (x)} (u(y))^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1} d s \\
&= \frac 1 {n\omega_n r^{n-1}}  \int_{\partial B_r (x)} (u(y))^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1} 
\end{align*} as required.